# clear() clears the value but retains the value in Selenium Appium when sendkeys() is used

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

clear method clears the value but retains and when send keys new value is passed the text box shows previous value + new value in selenium Appium. Kindly suggest.
Version:java-client-4.1.2
Appium Server:v1.7.2
Selenium: 3.0.1

```
I tried this but it did not work out.

public void clearTextBox(WebElement element,String text) throws Exception
  {
     element.click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     element.clear();
     element.sendKeys(text);
  }
```

Getting this [image]

[image]

Comment: You should use first `driver.findElement(editFieldId).clear();` then
`driver.findElement(editFieldId).sendKeys("ABC");`

Comment: I am using the below mentioned code but it is not working.
It appends the previous number + new number which is sent in sendKeys()

Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.click();      
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.clear();
Thread.sleep(3000);
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(msisdn);

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing (and you should have included your code in the original question) is because you are doing it through TWO separate calls to the page object element.

Each time you call the page object, it looks-up the element freshly, so the first time you call it and issue a .clear() and then you are calling it again after an unnecesary sleep with the .sendkeys() method.  The click is also unnecessary.

You should write a public method in your page object model to perform the sendkeys() for you which does the clear() and then the sendkeys(), i.e.:

```
public void setMsisdnValue(String text) {
    Msisdn.clear();
    Msisdn.sendKeys(text);
}
```

Personally, I use a set of helper methods so that I can error-trap and log things like sendkeys, but I would still call it from within the page object model itself.  That helper would do the same two steps, but also do it inside a try/catch and report any errors, so it would be simplified to:

```
public void setMsisdnValue(String text) {
    helper.sendKeys(Msisdn, text);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. But in the above code:
public void setMsisdnValue(String text) {
    Msisdn.clear();
    Msisdn.sendKeys(text);
}    
you are again calling it again and again

Msisdn in above is the locator for the text field which is same in both.

Comment: I tried this but it did not worked out.

 public void clearTextBox(WebElement element,String text) throws Exception
   {
   element.click();
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   element.clear();
   element.sendKeys(text);
   }

Comment: What is the xpath or other locator you're using for the web element?  I was hoping for a screenshot of the uiautomator which shows the layout information.  I thought I remembered replying to your first comment, but I don't see it anymore.  Must have been deleted or I'm getting old.

Comment: Added i am using ID:                                        
@FindBy(how=How.ID, using="com.android.phone:id/voicemail_dialog")
 public static WebElement Msisdn;

Comment: It all looks correct to me, including your locator.  What exactly are you trying to pass to the textview - what we're already seeing?  And to clarify, it's behaving like the clear does not work, then just appends whatever you send?  I'm not certain what the current versions of Appium or the java driver for Appium are, but I did notice that your Selenium version is 3.0.1, which if memory serves, had some problems.  The current version is 3.11.0.  You might try checking the versions of each component and updating them one-at-a-time.

Comment: I am sending msisdn value from feature file "9560038686"  and the existing value in the EditText box is "7827415733" it clears the box than when I sendkeys it adds to the existing value as shown in the Snapshot attached.